# The function field of $V=Z(y^2-x^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field and let $V=Z(y^2-x^3).$

Can someone explain to me why $k(V)\cong k(s,t)$ ??

with $t=x+(y^2-x^3),s=y+(y^2-x^3)\in A(V)=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3).$

Can we generalize it  : If $V=Z(f)$ with $f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be an irreducible polynomial and $t_i=x_i+(f)$ then $k(V)\cong k(t_1,\dots,t_n).$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact it isn't true that $K(V) \simeq k(s,t)$. For example, in your proposed isomorphism the elements $t$ and $s$ are algebraically dependent: $t^3=s^2$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh ; You can find this example in Patrick'Book Field and Galois theory p 201.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood exactly what you were asking. Often the notation $k(s,t)$ means a purely transcendental extension of $k$ of transcendence degree 2. I guess in this case the claim is just that $k(V)$ is generated by $s$ and $t$. That follows because $k(V)$ is (by definition) generated by $k[V]$, and $k[V]$ is generated by $s$ and $t$ because they are the images of $x$ and $y$, which generate $k[x,y]$.